# Filter out the pages using Facebook Graph Api / FQL

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

Having the following url I get all the pages I admin and applications I created. My goal is to show all the pages I admin and not the applications in an external PHP file.

https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts?access_token=xxx

Is there another url for this specific task or I have to find a way of filtering the follow? The fields are the same.

```
{
"data": [
      {
         "name": "",
         "access_token": "",
         "category": "Professional sports team",
         "id": "159960057362822"
      },
      {
         "name": "",
         "access_token": "",
         "category": "Application",
         "id": "155960053362822"
      }
]
}
```

The same goes using FQL like `SELECT page_id, type from page_admin WHERE uid=me()`
it shows the applications also.

**I have not created pages for applications.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the Graph API you'll need to iterate over results to manually filter everything with category `Application` (currently where is no filtering for this in Graph API)

With FQL you can do this by issuing next query:

```
SELECT page_id, type FROM page_admin WHERE uid = me()
  AND type != 'APPLICATION'
  AND type != 'APP'
```

Comment: Thank you for this. Should I read the contents using simpleXML ?

Comment: Can you answer me this please?

Comment: @Kaoukkos, While you can do it using REST API (which is going to be deprecated soon) I would not recommend it. If you're using PHP-SDK why not just `$results = $facebook->api('/fql', array('q'=>'FQL_QUERY'));`. If you not than just issue `GET` request to `http://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=FQL_QUERY_HERE`